# How to fix the Dell Mini 10v (1010) touchpad with Ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: 12.04, dell, touchpad, dell-mini-10

I've just installed 12.04.1 from scratch on my Mini 10v, and the touchpad is behaving a bit oddly.

It's got buttons integrated into the touchpad, and it looks as though a touch on a button is also being registered as a touch on the touchpad, causing all sorts of problems with clicking and dragging.

Is there a fix for this? I seem to remember on very old versions of ubuntu having to disable the lower part of the touchpad, but I don't think it's been an issue for some time.

Comment: I am afraid that's not the case, and, apparently, you still need to disable the bottom, and possibly left and right, strips.

Comment: Thanks Mike, any idea how I do that?

Comment: Yep. Check out the answer below. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable a strip at the bottom, you'd use `synclient AreaBottomEdge=xxx`, where xxx is a number which is less then the vertical width of the touchpad.

For example, on my Dell mini 10 (1010) with an Elantech touchpad, I had to use the following:

```
synclient AreaBottomEdge=690
```

...while the touchpad dimentions are:

```
~$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep range
[    24.008] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 1152
[    24.008] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 768
```

You can use `AreaLeftEdge`, `AreaRightEdge` and `AreaTopEdge` options in a similar manner, if needed.

To make the change permanent, I had to create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with the folloing content:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
        MatchProduct "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "synaptics"
        Option "AreaBottomEdge" "690"
        Option "AreaRightEdge" "1070"
        Option "AreaLeftEdge" "110"
EndSection
```

PS: You can find out how your Mini 10v's touchpad is identified by looking at the Xorg log info - 
`cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep touch`.